# The dervative of a multi-dimensional path integral

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, partial-derivative

Let the dimension be arbitrary.
I want to calculate

$$ L_i\equiv \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \int_{x-\epsilon/2}^{x+\epsilon/2} d\mathbf{z} \cdot \mathbf{A} $$

There are two ways to manipulate.
Strictly speaking, in order to postulate the existence of $\phi$ such that
$$ d\phi(\mathbf{z}) =A_i dz_i \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad \frac{\partial \phi(\mathbf{z})}{\partial z_i}  =A_i \,, $$
(where repeated indices follow the Einstein summation convention), we need the condition
$$ \frac{\partial A_j}{\partial z_i}  = \frac{\partial A_i}{\partial z_j} . $$
But we assume it in most cases.

**Method 1**
\begin{alignat}{2}
L_i &=&& \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \int_{x-\epsilon/2}^{x+\epsilon/2} d\phi \\
&=&& \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} (\phi(x+\epsilon/2)-\phi(x-\epsilon/2)) \\
&=&& \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \left( \phi(x)+ \frac{\epsilon_j}{2} \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} \phi(x)-\phi(x) -\frac{-\epsilon_j}{2} \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} \phi(x) + {\cal O}(\epsilon^2) \right) \\
&=&& \epsilon_j \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} A_j + {\cal O}(\epsilon^2) 
\end{alignat}

**Method 2**
\begin{alignat}{2}
L_i &=&& \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \int_{x-\epsilon/2}^{x+\epsilon/2} d\phi \\
&=&& \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \phi(x+\epsilon/2) - \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \phi(x-\epsilon/2) \\
&=&& A_i(x+\epsilon/2) - A_i(x-\epsilon/2) \\
&=&& A_i(x) + \frac{\epsilon_j}{2} \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}  A_i -A_i(x) - \frac{-\epsilon_j}{2} \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}  A_i +{\cal O}(\epsilon^2) \\
&=&& \epsilon_j \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}  A_i +{\cal O}(\epsilon^2)
\end{alignat}

It seems to me that both methods are correct.
Which method is correct?
(This question is related with [this post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/285532/a-derivative-about-chiral-current-in-peskins-book).)
Thanks.

Comment: unclear. You should write everything explicitly in the form $\frac{\partial}{\partial h}C\int_0^1 f(x_0+hv+t a) dt=C\int_0^1 \frac{\partial}{\partial h}f(x_0+hv+t a) dt$

Comment: @user1952009 : Is it OK now?

Comment: If you are not sure, then replace $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} f$ by $\frac{\partial }{\partial h} f(x+hv) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+hv)-f(x)}{h}$ the [directional derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directional_derivative) in the direction $v$ (since $g(h) = f(x+hv)$ is a function of the real variable $h$, its derivative is well-defined)

Comment: I'm a physicist. I used the notation of Special reativity ($ x+\epsilon/2 \equiv \mathbf{x}+\mathbf{\epsilon}/2 $). Is it familiar for mathematicians?

Comment: We don't have any problem with that, but you do, so use the most explicit and rigorous notation

Comment: "but you do," It sounds like I stumbled in the notation, isn't it?

Comment: You need to write everything explicitely : $A$ is a vector field i.e. $A(z) = [A_1(z),\ldots,A_n(z)]\in \mathbb{R}^n$  and $dz.A(z) = \sum_{m=1}^n A_m(z)dz_m$ so **by definition** $\int_{x -\epsilon/2}^{x +\epsilon/2} dz.A = \int_{x -\epsilon/2}^{x +\epsilon/2} \sum_{m=1}^n A_m(z)dz_m = \sum_{m=1}^n \int_0^1A_m(x -\epsilon/2+t \epsilon)  d(t \epsilon)_m $ $= \sum_{m=1}^n \epsilon_m \int_0^1A_m(x -\epsilon/2+t \epsilon)  dt $ and differentiating this last expression is trivial

Comment: @user1952009 : The right answer is : $$ \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \int_{x-\epsilon/2}^{x+\epsilon/2} d\phi= \sum_{m=1}^n \epsilon_m \int_0^1 \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} A_m(x -\epsilon/2+t \epsilon)  dt = \sum_{m=1}^n \epsilon_m \int_0^1 \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} A_m(x) +{\cal o}(\epsilon) \right) dt = \sum_{m=1}^n \epsilon_m \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} A_m(x) +{\cal o}(|\mathbf{\epsilon}|^2) $$

Comment: @user1952009 : And the original problem at phys.SE probably assumes the fixed path of the integral as $z=x -\epsilon/2+t \epsilon$. So the definite integral doesn't depend on only $x-\epsilon/2$ and $x+\epsilon/2$, then we cannot  postulate the existence of $\phi$. If we postuated it, the both methods would give the same result. Do you agree now?

Comment: Yes I agree that with $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \int_{x-\epsilon/2}^{x+\epsilon/2} d\phi= \sum_{m=1}^n \epsilon_m \int_0^1 \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} A_m(x -\epsilon/2+t \epsilon)  dt = \sum_{m=1}^n \epsilon_m \int_0^1 \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} A_m(x) +{\cal o}(\epsilon) \right) dt = \sum_{m=1}^n \epsilon_m \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} A_m(x) +{\cal o}(|\mathbf{\epsilon}|^2)$ you are on the right track : write everything clearly and rigorously and it will become trivial.

Comment: @user1952009 : Sorry, I mistyped.  The right starting point is $L_i = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \int_{x-\epsilon/2}^{x+\epsilon/2} d\mathbf{z} \cdot \mathbf{A}$.

Answer (score 1):

The point is that in general cases we cannot postulate the existence of  $\phi$ such that
$$ d\phi(\mathbf{z}) =A_i dz_i \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad \frac{\partial \phi(\mathbf{z})}{\partial z_i}  =A_i \, . $$
Only when the condition $ \frac{\partial A_j}{\partial z_i}  = \frac{\partial A_i}{\partial z_j}  $ is satisfied, $\phi$ exists.

The correct calculation goes as follows. 
\begin{alignat}{2}
L_i &=&& \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}  \sum_{m=1}^n \int_0^1A_m(x -\epsilon/2+t \epsilon)  d(t \epsilon)_m \\
&=&& \sum_{m=1}^n \epsilon_m \int_0^1 \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} A_m(x -\epsilon/2+t \epsilon)  dt  \\
&=&& \sum_{m=1}^n \epsilon_m \int_0^1 \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} A_m(x) +{\cal O}(|\mathbf{\epsilon}|) \right) dt \\
&=&& \sum_{m=1}^n \epsilon_m \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} A_m(x) +{\cal O}(|\mathbf{\epsilon}|^2) 
\end{alignat}

If we restrice the situation to the cases where $\frac{\partial A_j}{\partial z_i}  = \frac{\partial A_i}{\partial z_j} $ is satisfied, both methods are correct. Then the results will be the same :
$$ L_i = \sum_{j=1}^n \epsilon_j \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} A_j + {\cal O}(|\mathbf{\epsilon}|^2)  $$
(n : the dimension of the vector space)

Comment: @user1952009 : Thank you so much for your assistance!